# QGIS callouts label anchor point missing

Tags: qgis, labeling, callout, anchor-point

I have QGIS 3.16.3. According to the QGIS documentation in label-callouts setting is option anchor point. However I don´t have this option (picture below). Where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: What about the last entry, at the bottom of your screenshot?

Comment: it is label anchor point, not anchor point.

Comment: What kind of anchor point are you refering to? You refer to qgis documentation: can you post a link to it?

Comment: This is only available for *Polygon* layers!

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @geozelot, this functionality is available only for polygon layers. You can use this for a workaround: create an extremely small buffer around your line and set the label there. You can than set the symbology of the buffer layer to `No Symbology` to keep only the label:

[image]